# How to add a column in one shapefile that is the sum of values in another shapefile?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, hydrology, hydrology-toolset

I am trying to calculate a weighted average CN value for 500 drainage area catchments (S1-S500).
I have one file named "*DA*" which has S1-S500.
Name    Total_Area
S1      1.5
S2      0.8
........ and so on
[image]

I have another shapefile named "*Intersect*" which has 2649 lines

[image]

How to add a column field for "*S1*" in a shape file "*DA*" from shapefile "*intersect*" that is the sum of the values in column "*CNA*" for values with an S1 and then S2 etc.? In this example, there are only three S1 rows in "*Intersect*" shape file.  But there are 5-15 rows for some of the S values.
See actual screenshot of both attribute tables:
[image]

Comment: You could add both shapefiles to a sqlite database and then do a SQL query along the lines of `update DA set cumulated_sum=sum(cn) from DA inner join Intersects on DA.NAME = Intersects.NAME group by DA.NAME`. The exact Syntax may differ. If nobody else comes around with a better way I can try working out the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a field calculator expression on your DA layer like so:

```sql
aggregate(
    layer:='intersect',                           -- the layer to aggregate
    aggregate:='sum',                             -- sum the aggregated values
    expression:="CNA",                            -- the value to sum
    filter:=attribute(@parent, 'NAME') = "NAME"   -- use only features in the intersect layer whose Name field match the Name field in the current layer (DA)
)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I am getting the filter wrong.  Sorry I am not a pro at expressions. I tried this:aggregate( Intersection,sum,CNA,attribute(@parent,'Name') = NAME)

Comment: I really appreciate the help; this is exactly what I need. I just need to get the syntax.  Thank You

Comment: As your field names are capital letters, you may need to enclose them in double quotes `"NAME"`. Don't forget to capitalise the one inside the `attribute` function. This one should keep its single quotes though, because it is a function argument, not a reference to a field itself. A little confusing but it gets easier with practice :)  I updated my expression with the correct capitalisation. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I still cannot get the expression to work.  I noticed the CNA field I had wasn't correct as it should be CNA_ac. I tried this  aggregate( Intersection, sum, CNA_ac, attribute(@parent,'NAME')="NAME")     Eval error says Cannot find layer with name or ID". So close but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Put CNA_ac also in double quotes: `"CNA_ac"`. If it was all all lowercase letters you can get away without, but field names with capitals or spaces must be quoted. `'intersection'` and `'sum'` must also have single quotes as they are function arguments.

Comment: That did it.  I seriously cannot thank you enough.  This saved me hours of work. If you do contract work or know of people who will write some custom code to do other stuff like this, please let me know.  Thanks